# Difference between array.GetLength(0) and array.GetUpperBound(0)

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

What is the difference between these two methods and when would you use one instead of the other?

```
int[,] array = new int[4,3];
int length0 = array.GetLength(0);
int upperbound0 = array.GetUpperBound(0);
```

MSDN says that GetLength return the number of elements where as GetUpperBound determine the max index, but how could this be different since arrays are initialized with elements for each index?

Comment: You assume the lower bound is always zero.  It is not.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Take a look at this (rarely used) method. From [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.array.createinstance?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Array_CreateInstance_System_Type_System_Int32___System_Int32___):

> `public static Array CreateInstance(Type elementType, int[] lengths, int[] lowerBounds)`
>
> Creates a multidimensional Array of the specified Type and dimension lengths, with the specified lower bounds.

With it, you can create an array with indices from `-5 ... +5`. If you ever use this kind of array, then `GetUpperBound()` suddenly becomes a lot more useful than `GetLength()-1`. There also exists a `GetLowerBound()`.

But the C# support for this kind of arrays is low, you cannot use `[]`. You would only need those methods in combination with the  Array.GetValue() and SetValue() methods.

Answer (score 11):

`Array.Length` returns the length of the array (number of elements) you need
to subtract 1 from it to get the UpperBound.

`Array.GetUpperBound(0)` returns the upper bound of the array, you can use it
as is.

Answer (score 3):

`GetUpperBound` returns the highest index in the array, the `GetLength` returns the number of elements of the array.

i.e. GetUpperBound = GetLength - 1

Comment: Usually. But that's not why it's provided.

Comment: +1 to your answer, did not know that you could start an array at an index other than 0!

Answer (score 3):

Generally, `array.GetUpperBound(0) = array.Length - 1`, but since we can create arrays that have a Nonzero lower bound, that is not always true.

Answer (score 2):

I realise this is an old question but I think it's worth emphasising that [GetUpperBound](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.getupperbound?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Array_GetUpperBound_System_Int32_) returns the upper boundary of the specified dimension. This is important for a multidimensional array as in that case the two functions are not equivalent.

```
// Given a simple two dimensional array
private static readonly int[,] USHolidays =
{
    { 1, 1 },
    { 7, 4 },
    { 12, 24 },
    { 12, 25 }
};
```

The Length property will output 8 as there are 8 elements in the array.

```
Console.WriteLine(USHolidays.Length);
```

However, the GetUpperBound() function will output 3 as the upper boundary of the first dimension is 3. In other words I can loop over array indexes 0, 1, 2 and 3.

```
Console.WriteLine(USHolidays.GetUpperBound(0));
for (var i = 0; i <= USHolidays.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", USHolidays[i, 0], USHolidays[i, 1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if lower bound of your array is 0 then you can use either of them without any confusion but i would recommend array.length-1 as it is widely used. however, if the lower bound of your array is less than 0 then you should use array.GetUpperBound(0) because in this case array.length-1 != array.getUpperBound(0)