# How to create variable dimension array at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, reflection, multidimensional-array

I want to create variable length multi-dimension array at runtime.

**Input** -> Array that has length of each dimension. Number of dimensions = length of input array.
**Output** -> variable dimension array.

Example:
Input -> `var lengths = new [] {3,4,5}`
Expected output -> `var arr = new string[3,4,5]`

How to do that without and with reflection?

Comment: And how would you access it? And lets not forget that var is not what you think it is.

Comment: That is another question, that i am figuring out. But I am sure if i can get the array created, I would get sufficient information for accessing it

Comment: Thats part of the question you are asking. I think you should tell us what kind of problem are you trying to solve first.

Comment: This question is out of curiosity for the language constructs. For anything practical, this can be managed with simpler collections.

Comment: downvoter any explanation?

Answer (score 3):

There is this method in the System.Array class :

```
public static Array CreateInstance(
Type elementType,
int[] lengths    
)
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7202515/60761) for a discussion of `GetLength()` and `GetUpperBound()`

But do note that because you don't know the dimensions at compile time you cannot use the familiar `a[i,j,k]` syntax. All access would look like   `int[] indices = ...; object x = a.GetValue(indices);`