# Negative index arrays in .NET

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, clr

The [`Array.BinarySearch(Array array, object value)` method's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.binarysearch?view=netframework-4.8#System_Array_BinarySearch_System_Array_System_Object_) mentions that

> This method does not support searching arrays that contain negative indexes.

If you look at its [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,c9d30a83673759f0), there's a comment inside the `GetMedian(int low, int hi)` method that states:

```cs
// Note both may be negative, if we are dealing with arrays w/ negative lower bounds.
Contract.Requires(low <= hi);
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but C# by itself has no notion of negative-index arrays and there is no such thing as an array's lower bound (like an `Array.LowerBound` property or something). That would lead me to the conclusion that while C# does not, CLR itself does allow negatively indexed arrays. Am I correct? Is there a .NET language that has such arrays? *Why* would you even have such arrays in the first place?

Bonus imaginary points if there's a reflection voodoo ritual one can perform to get a negatively indexed array in C# and break the fabric of reality.

Comment: in c# you can write your own indexer. I would use it for opposite values???? Edit: Or never.

Comment: Sure they have lower bounds. Via Array.GetLowerBound. And you can create an array with a negative lower bound with Array.CreateInstance.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7202515/60761

Comment: Non-conformant arrays are pretty common in COM libraries, albeit that the index of the first element is usually 1 instead of a negative value.  Many languages were ported to .NET, Pascal for example.